# jQuery Template issue - not rendering

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

i have the following template

```
<script id="employeeTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td>${Name}</td>
        <td>${Designation}</td>
        <td>{{if Age>30}}
            <span style='background-color: red'>Middle-aged</span>
            {{else}}
            <span style='background-color: yellow'>Still young</span>
            {{/if}}</td>
        <td>${Department}</td>
        <td>${DataSource}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

and the following functions

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function BindClientSideData() {
        //JSON data format
        var emps = [
        { Name: "John", Designation: "Analyst", Age: 25, Department: "IT", DataSource: "Client" },
        { Name: "Matthew", Designation: "Manager", Age: 38, Department: "Accounts", DataSource: "Client" },
        { Name: "Emma", Designation: "Senior Manager", Age: 40, Department: "HR", DataSource: "Client" },
        { Name: "Sid", Designation: "Analyst", Age: 27, Department: "HR", DataSource: "Client" },
        { Name: "Tom", Designation: "Senior Analyst", Age: 35, Department: "IT", DataSource: "Client" }
        ];
        BindTable(emps);
    }

    function BindTable(data) {
        // removes existing rows from table except header row
        $('#tblEmployee tr:gt(0)').remove();
        //apply tmpl plugin to <script> and append result to table
      //  $("#employeeTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#tblEmployee");
       $("#tblEmployee").loadTemplate("#employeeTemplate", data);
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that when BindClientSideData() is called, i get the following output

```
    ${Name} ${Designation} {{if Age>30}} Middle-aged {{else}} Still young {{/if}} ${Department} ${DataSource} 
${Name} ${Designation} {{if Age>30}} Middle-aged {{else}} Still young {{/if}} ${Department} ${DataSource} 
${Name} ${Designation} {{if Age>30}} Middle-aged {{else}} Still young {{/if}} ${Department} ${DataSource} 
${Name} ${Designation} {{if Age>30}} Middle-aged {{else}} Still young {{/if}} ${Department} ${DataSource} 
${Name} ${Designation} {{if Age>30}} Middle-aged {{else}} Still young {{/if}} ${Department} ${DataSource}
```

Can someone please let me know why the temaplate is not loading data.

I am referencing the jQuery 19.2 and jQuery.tmpl.js

Tried changing syntax etc of jQuery temaplate but no luck. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#tblEmployee").loadTemplate($("#employeeTemplate"), data);
```

instead of

```
$("#tblEmployee").loadTemplate("#employeeTemplate", data);
```

here is an example with jquery tmpl with a different syntax.

```
$.tmpl($('#employeeTemplate'), data).appendTo('#tblEmployee');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyPmm/)**

Comment: when i use the following: $.tmpl($('#employeeTemplate'), data).appendTo('#tblEmployee');, i get tmpl not found and the other syntax provided is producing the same result.

Comment: Can u replicate it in a fiddle.

Comment: Is ur tmpl script loaded properly

Comment: i think the tmpl is loaded properly. can you send me a link to the tmpl file you know works for sure.

Comment: See the external resources in my fiddle on the left

Comment: that was it. replaced the tmpl file and it's woking now using your suggested syntax. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to append `jQuery`, template:

```
$("#bookTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#dvProductsGrid");
```